# OrmLite should db operations happen in main thread?

Tags: android, orm, ormlite

From the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29) it mentions that when you call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` you should always do it on a background thread.

I use OrmLite for my app and it when I call `getHelper()` I call it from the UI/main thread.

I also have `StrictMode` enabled for my app and I do not remember seeing warnings in logcat.

What is the preferred way of using this? What about any SQL operations such as `insert` or `update` in my `Dao` objects? Should they happen in a background thread?

Comment: if you're running in strict mode and got no exception, it is done in a background thread

Comment: The main thread should only do instant operations that require only in-memory data. Once it goes to the filesystem (read/write the database) or to the network it's bad. The thing about `getWritableDatabase()` that you don't want to happen is creation of a complex database (i.e. `onCreate`/`onUpgrade` in the database helper doing a lot of work) - it is okay once the database is created, that is just a bit of file IO on the main thread.

Comment: Whenever I use the `Dao` objects I never see anything in `StrictMode` log. Does OrmLite wrap these operations in a background thread?

Comment: ORMLite does nothing with threads automatically.  The thread that you make the DAO call in is the one that will perform the database operations.

Comment: @Gray so does this mean that we should be doing DB operations in a background thread instead?

Comment: StrictMode does not appear to complain when a `Dao.create` or any other `Dao` operation is invoked.

Comment: it depends on the operation.  I know of a ton of applications which do it in the foreground.  This is necessary if you need to wait for the data.  If you are doing some large (multi-second) operation and can do it in the background then you should.